# Postgres Array Prefix Matching

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an array search in Postgres hat matches at least one tag as this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE tags && ['fun'];

| id | tags      |
| 1  | [fun,day] | 
| 2  | [fun,sun] |
```

It is possible to match on prefixes? Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE tags LIKE 'f%';

| id | tags      |
| 1  | [fun,day] | 
| 2  | [fun,sun] |
| 3  | [far]     | 
| 4  | [fin]     |
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
create table users (id serial primary key, tags text[]);

insert into users (tags)
values
  ('{"fun", "day"}'),
  ('{"fun", "sun"}'),
  ('{"test"}'),
  ('{"fin"}');

select *
from users
where exists (select * from unnest(tags) as arr where arr like 'f%')
```

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/a6940/2)

Comment: That EXISTS clause is incorrect -- look at the results. It is missing a reference to the outer query to associate the rows. Try adding AND `id = u.id` (is "u" is the alias for the outer table). Fiddle updated: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/a6940/10/0

Comment: I have not much expirience in PostgreSQL (mostly in SQL server), but I'm pretty sure you're wrong about it, and BTW my query returns correct result in sqlfiddle.
Exists is already working on current row tags, so your id = u.id. SQLFIDDLE is down at the moment, so I'll check it later.

Comment: basically my query could be rewritten as 
`select * from users as u where exists (select * from unnest(u.tags) as arr where arr like 'f%')`

Comment: Hmmm, looks like you are correct about your SQL Fiddle example. I must have misused it when I tested it. My apologies.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a working example that should get you more or less what you're after. Note that I am not claiming that this approach will scale...

```
create table users (
id      serial primary key,
tags    text[] not null
);

insert into users (tags) values
('{"aaaa","bbbb","cccc"}'::text[]),
('{"badc","dddd","eeee"}'::text[]),
('{"gggg","ffbb","attt"}'::text[]);

select *
from (select id,unnest(tags) arr from users) u
where u.arr like 'a%';

 id | arr  
----+------
  1 | aaaa
  3 | attt
```